# How to clear cache on Android or iOS to read a BLE characteristic?

Tags: android, ios, caching, bluetooth-lowenergy

A very strange thing happens on Android and iOS : when you want to "read" a BLE characteristic, it doesn't always issue a "read" to the connected device. It seems to read into a cache and return the value if there were no notification in between.

I have noticed that because I am making a step counter device and if I do the following :

- connect to device
- subscribe to step count notification
- make 100 steps
- disconnect
- make 15 more steps with my device
- connect and make a read
- I will read 100 instead of 115
- I make one more step and receive a notification. The count I receive is 116

on Windows (PC) when I do a read, there is this option `BluetoothCacheMode`. Is there such an option on Android or iOS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the caching was done in the firmware by default